# JAVA_HOME directory does not contains jar which is required to process Play Services dependencies

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

I got this error when trying to install leaderboard for my game by using Google Play Service, as a pop up message:

[image: error-popup]

and with some details in the output:

[image: error-detail]

Do you have an advice how can I fix this error? Thank you very much.

Comment: Updated the question with the requested details ?

Comment: it's incredibly hard to do this. in practice, most folks use the Prime31 plugin for the purpose. (It's still a lot of work!)

Comment: You can inline your images so that people can see everything in context and don't need to click links. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) how it's done or click the [edited...](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40565098/revisions) above (and "side-by-side Markdown") to see the edit history of your post.

Comment: Thanks you, I'm new in stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 2):

The `JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to a sub folder of the JDK location, rather than the actual JDK folder itself. Change it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111`.